# Leave CSS Grid cell empty without specifying other elements position explicitly

Tags: html, css

I want to have icon class element self positioned in center in relation to first row and skip cell in second row first column.

Is there a way to skip that cell without specifying third class div grid-column position explicitly. I can not use grid-row: span 2 on icon because then it will be positioned in center of two rows.

Any chance to skip specific cell when declaring grid-template?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 200px 200px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.icon {
  align-self: center;
}

.third {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="icon">
    Icon
  </div>
  <div>
    First field
  </div>
  <div>
    Second field
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    Third field
  </div>
  <div>
    Fourth field
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's wrong with grid-column: 2? that's your declaration to skip the cell. In all the cases, you need to do something so if not grid-column:2 it will be something else

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong. I was just unable to find anywhere if it is even possible to skip a cell. I only found that you can do that using grid-template-areas and specifying dot in place of empty cell but that doesn't help as you still need to specify other items grid-area.

Comment: you just found a way to skip a cell, You don't need to search more

Answer (score -1):

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px dotted #222;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "icon tl tr"
                       "blank bl br";
}

.grid > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  grid-area: icon;
  background: #b4d455;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.tl {
  grid-area: tl;
}

.tr {
  grid-area: tr;
}

.br {
  grid-area: br;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="icon">Icon</div>
  <div class="tl">Top left</div>
  <div class="tr">Top right</div>
  <div class="br">Bottom right</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This would probably work, but I already see that this is exactly what I was trying to avoid. You explicitly specifying grid-area for each item. Instead I was looking for solution (or answer that it is not possible) how to skip exact cell (row/column) when defining grid-template, so I can avoid setting classes on elements and specifying their position.